# DateTime is not storing in mysql database during form submission in php

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am new to PHP and MySql. I am trying to insert simple form into MySql database. I have Apache/PHP/MySql in my machine. I am sorry if this is repetitive question. But i searched lot and not able to find the solution.

I have 3 html input fields 'name', 'age', 'sex' and inserting it into mysql with 4 columns in the insert query. The 4th column is 'datetime' column. Below are my structure.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql_query = "insert into demoform (name, age, sex, Created_On)
              values('$name', '$age', '$sex', '$date')";
$result = $db_conn->query($sql_query);
```

But after i do the insert, php form submitted successfully. But in the table, the date column show as "0000-00-00 00:00:00".

can anyone help me what am i doing wrong here?

*Question updated with the table structure...

```
mysql> show tables;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_myphpdb |
+-------------------+
| demoform          |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe demoform;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| age        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sex        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Created_On | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please provide database structure of **demoform** table

Comment: try $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

Comment: Maybe a typo `Created_On` != `created_on`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php check your table/column and if you chose the right db/table/column. Use error reporting also http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Output `$sql_query`, what does the query generate as? You should use prepared statements as well.

Comment: @tino.codes `Created_On` and `created_on` should both work. That is only case-sensitive when querying the row in a SELECT.

Comment: Make sure that your column is called `Created_On` and not `CreatedOn` without the underscore and if your table isn't set as case-sensitivity. Checking for errors on your query will tell you that. Provide db schema to leave the guesswork out here. Plus, maybe the rest of your inputs failed, who knows. I can't see how this would fail.

Comment: i have updated the question with table structure.

Comment: again, check for errors everywhere, for your db, table, PHP etc. that I have outlined already further above. I can't see how this would fail. Ask the guy who gave you an answer below.

Comment: print you query and run @mmar

Comment: Do this; I have a feeling your query is erroring out, but you're not checking for errors.
 `$date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conn, $date);`

Comment: when i print my query line, i get this output. "insert into demoform (name, age, sex, Created_On) values('', '', '', '2015-10-31 12:51:20')" for now i commented the other fields..

Comment: There, see? I said that earlier *"Plus, maybe the rest of your inputs failed"*. Your other inputs have failed you. You didn't show us where all those other variables are coming from. That's why you're getting all 0's.

Comment: No, i said i have commented the other fields for now to echo the '$sql_query' variable. when i do 'echo $sql_query', i get the above output. (again, i commented my name, age, sex field for echo purpose.)

Comment: this is the 3rd and last time I will say this: **check for errors**, or take it up with the guy who gave you an answer below. I am moving on now, good luck.

Comment: Thanks Fred for your time, I appreciate your support on your busy time.

Comment: try to change the field name Created_On to some other

Answer (score 1):

use MySQL `NOW()`

```
$sql_query = "insert into demoform (name, age, sex, Created_On)
 values('$name', '$age', '$sex', NOW())";
```

if you need current date time use MySQL `now()`

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question as to "why" their code is failing. datetime is what their column is set as.